# Executing a tcpstat command and performing operations on its output simultaneously

Tags: linux, perl, tcp, icmp

I am trying to run a **tcpstat** command that gives the output about number of **icmp** requests being received. and at the same time i need to check the count so that if it exceeds some threshold, a message should be displayed.

i tried out something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @count= system "tcpstat -i eth1 -f icmp[0]==8 -o %C";

my $i=0;
while ($i<1000)
{
print "count of packets is :".$count[$i]."\n";
$i=$i+1;
if($count[$i]>50)
{   
print "thats a lot of pings";
}
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work because.. the execution of the command doesn't end without an user interrupt...

is it possible to do that? running the command and simultaneously performing operations over its output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your `tcpstat` command in shell and pipe the output to your `perl` script.

```
tcpstat -i eth1 -f icmp[0]==8 -o %C  |  perl script.pl
```

In this way, you should expect your input from `<STDIN>` and remove the `system` call in perl, of course.

Comment: the same issue.. it gives me a blank screen with a blinking cursor.
possibly because the control doesn't go to the while loop until the tcp stat command finishes its execution.

Comment: To trace it you can add some `print` calls and know where it is blocked. Consider whether the input received is being buffered or not. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351500/perl-disable-buffering-input